# Drupal log in perl

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$regex = '<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="(.*?)" />';
my $target = "http://localhost/lab/dr/?q=user";
$search = $ua->get ($target)->content;
if ($search =~/$regex/){
my $post = $ua->post($target,
            {
            "name" => "M-A",
            "pass" => "Mr_c0der",
            "form_id"=>"user_login",
            "form_build_id" => $1,
            "op" => "Log in",
            });

print $post->content;
}
```

i don't know what's the problem no response-content and response->code = 302

Comment: A 302 is a redirection.  You need to follow the redirect.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302   I don't know why LWP::UA isn't following the redirects for you automatically.

Comment: You need to figure out if the 302 is because of the ->get() or the ->post().

Answer (score 0):

I would use [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) to do this, it's a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, the example you post would be trivial to port. It will cater for redirect after valid login automatically. It's a more convenient browser like object to work with I find.